# How to make the error messages form only appear when actual error messages are generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the RailsSpace tutorial. My error form is being displayed always. It's always on! I don't know how to make it go away. I know that using @user.errors.clear will actually clear the messages. I tried using it in the view but no error messages will display at all. I appreciate your help.

Here is the error form code:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div id="errorExplanation">
  <h2>Please fix the following <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>:</h2>

  <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @title = "NubeMart Hub!"
  end

  def register
   @user = User.new
    @title = "Register"
    if request.post?

      @user = User.create(ad_params)
    end

      if @user.save

        flash[:notice]="User #{@user.screen_name} created!"
        redirect_to :action=>"index"
      end

  end

  def ad_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:screen_name, :email, :password)
  end

end
```

And here is my view:

```
<h2>Register</h2>

<%= form_for :user do |form| %>

  <%= render "shared/form_errors", :user => @user %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Your Details</legend>

    <div class="form_row">
      <label for="screen_name">Screen name:</label>
      <%= form.text_field :screen_name,
                          :size => User::SCREEN_NAME_SIZE,
                          :maxlength => User::SCREEN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH %>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <%= form.text_field :email,
                          :size => User::EMAIL_SIZE,
                          :maxlength => User::EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH %>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <%= form.password_field :password,
                              :size => User::PASSWORD_SIZE,
                              :maxlength => User::PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH %>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
      <%= submit_tag "Register!", :class => "submit" %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your register method is wrong:

```
def register
  @user = User.new
  @title = "Register"
  if request.post?
    @user = User.create(ad_params)
  end
  if @user.save    # <== This block should be moved!
    flash[:notice]="User #{@user.screen_name} created!"
    redirect_to :action=>"index"
  end
end
```

This code `if @user.save` will execute even if the request isn't post. You have put this code outside of if block `if request.post?`.

I think the below code should solve your issue.

```
def register
  @title = "Register"
  if request.post?
    @user = User.new(ad_params) # I have changed create to new
    if @user.save               # here your user will be saved(inly in case of post request)
      flash[:notice]="User #{@user.screen_name} created!"
    end
  else
    @user = User.new # (this is when request is not post)
  end
  redirect_to :action=>"index"
end
```